# Laravel Eloquent Error (SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer) on import a large csv file

Tags: laravel, postgresql, csv

Im try to import a csv file with 130k rows,I do it with laravel excel but it takes a long time, so I chose to try the fast-excel library and csv league. With a small file, all 3 libraries have imported correctly.
But with the 130k csv file, fast-excel and csv league it gives me the following error:

```
"SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «» (SQL: insert into "uso_suelo" ("cod_pais", "cod_fundo", "nom_fundo", "cod_uso_suelo", "dsc_uso_suelo", "cod_rodal", "cod_especie", "dsc_especie", "ano_plantacion", "cod_esquema", "dsc_esquema", "dsc_restriccion_suelo", "sup_ha", "cod_z_cpino", "cod_z_prod", "cod_sz_prod", "dsc_sz_prod", "id_area_us", "updated_at", "created_at") values (90, 5196, LA PATAGUA, 4050, CORTAFUEGO, 0, , , , , , SIN RESTRICCION, 0.32, 7, 4, 17, NAHUELBUTA INTERIOR ALTA, 129660, 2020-04-29 10:45:24, 2020-04-29 10:45:24) returning "id")
```

In the migration of the table I have defined all the fields as nullable

This is the code with csv league library:

```
        $csv = Reader::createFromPath(storage_path('/app/uso_suelo.csv'));
        $csv->setHeaderOffset(0); //set the CSV header offset
        $records = $csv->getRecords();
        foreach ($records as $offset => $record) {  
            UsoSuelo::create([
                'cod_pais'     => $record['COD_PAIS'],
                'cod_fundo'     => $record['COD_FUNDO'],
                'nom_fundo'     => $record['NOM_FUNDO'],
                'cod_uso_suelo'     => $record['COD_USOSUELO'],
                'dsc_uso_suelo'     => $record['DSC_USOSUELO'],
                'cod_rodal'     => $record['COD_RODAL'],
                'cod_especie'     => $record['COD_ESPECIE'],
                'dsc_especie'     => $record['DSC_ESPECIE'],
                'ano_plantacion'     => $record['ANO_PLANTACION'],
                'cod_esquema'     => $record['COD_ESQUEMA'],
                'dsc_esquema'     => $record['DSC_ESQUEMA'],
                'dsc_restriccion_suelo'     => $record['DSC_RESTRICCION_SUELO'],
                'sup_ha'    => $record['SUP_HA'], 
                'cod_z_cpino'    => $record['COD_Z_CPINO'],
                'cod_z_prod'    => $record['COD_Z_PROD'], 
                'cod_sz_prod' => $record['COD_SZ_PROD'],
                'dsc_sz_prod' => $record['DSC_SZ_PROD'],
                'id_area_us' => $record['ID_AREA_US']
            ]);

}
```

And this is with fast-excel:

```
$usoSuelo = (new FastExcel)->import(storage_path('/app/uso_suelo.csv'), function ($line) {
            return UsoSuelo::create([
                'cod_pais'     => $line['COD_PAIS'],
                'cod_fundo'     => $line['COD_FUNDO'],
                'nom_fundo'     => $line['NOM_FUNDO'],
                'cod_uso_suelo'     => $line['COD_USOSUELO'],
                'dsc_uso_suelo'     => $line['DSC_USOSUELO'],
                'cod_rodal'     => $line['COD_RODAL'],
                'cod_especie'     => $line['COD_ESPECIE'],
                'dsc_especie'     => $line['DSC_ESPECIE'],
                'ano_plantacion'     => $line['ANO_PLANTACION'],
                'cod_esquema'     => $line['COD_ESQUEMA'],
                'dsc_esquema'     => $line['DSC_ESQUEMA'],
                'dsc_restriccion_suelo'     => $line['DSC_RESTRICCION_SUELO'],
                'sup_ha'    => $line['SUP_HA'], 
                'cod_z_cpino'    => $line['COD_Z_CPINO'],
                'cod_z_prod'    => $line['COD_Z_PROD'], 
                'cod_sz_prod' => $line['COD_SZ_PROD'],
                'dsc_sz_prod' => $line['DSC_SZ_PROD'],
                'id_area_us' => $line['ID_AREA_US']
            ]);
        });
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('uso_suelo', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('cod_pais')->nullable();
    $table->integer('cod_fundo')->nullable();
    $table->string('nom_fundo',100)->nullable();
    $table->integer('cod_uso_suelo')->nullable();
    $table->string('dsc_uso_suelo',100)->nullable();
    $table->integer('cod_rodal')->nullable();
    $table->integer('cod_especie')->nullable();
    $table->string('dsc_especie',100)->nullable();
    $table->integer('ano_plantacion')->nullable();
    $table->integer('cod_esquema')->nullable();
    $table->string('dsc_esquema',100)->nullable();
    $table->string('dsc_restriccion_suelo',100)->nullable();
    $table->float('sup_ha',8,2)->nullable();
    $table->integer('cod_z_cpino')->nullable();
    $table->integer('cod_z_prod')->nullable();
    $table->integer('cod_sz_prod')->nullable();
    $table->text('dsc_sz_prod')->nullable();
    $table->integer('id_area_us')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I know the error is because of the empty fields, but with 130k rows I must allow it to be omitted. The strange thing is that when importing them with laravel-excel this does not happen, the database is postgresql, and laravel version is 5.8

Comment: Try casting value to int, and empty strings to null for integer type columns. Ie: `'cod_especie' => $record['COD_ESPECIE']? (int) $record['COD_ESPECIE']: null,`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create an integer column. but you are trying to store a string. You can specify a value as `float` or`integer`

`(float) $line['COD_PAIS']`

also your are calling 130K insert query!. I'd suggest you to assign the value to array before calling insert

```
$data = [];
foreach ($records as $offset => $record) {
  $data[] = [
              'cod_pais' => $record['COD_PAIS'],
              'cod_fundo' => $record['COD_FUNDO'],
              'nom_fundo' => $record['NOM_FUNDO'],
               ...
            ]
}
UsoSuelo::insert($data);
```

Comment: The biggest source of errors in a spreadsheet is inappropriate data values. The suggestion by @Aslam is valid providing the excel column contains valid numeric data just not a integer(say 25.0 instead of 25). However, it would still fail should it contain something like "N/A" indication it doesn't apply. This may be the difference in your laraval-excel vs. your fast-excel. The laravel is checking data content while fast is not (that is how it gets fast). You may need to load into a staging table first and then migrate to your actual table on those rows meeting all data requirements.

Comment: Keep in mind a slow process that always works is far superior to a blazingly fast one that often fails.  BTW for the database prospective 130K rows is not that much.